# On Change of TabItem View not getting updated with the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

In my app there is this menu at the top with 3 items, - Add and Modify. Am using MahApps.Metro.
I got this TabControl approach from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796174/load-usercontrol-in-tabitem). Here is the menu.xaml, -

```
<Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Controls:TabControlHelper.IsUnderlined="True"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding FieldViewModels}"
                                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFieldViewModel}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AddFieldViewModel}">
            <view:AddFieldView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ModifyFieldViewModel}">
            <view:ModifyFieldView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ScriptFieldViewModel}">
            <view:ScriptFieldView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

In the MenuViewModel.cs I have, -

```
public MenuViewModel()
{
    fieldViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>();
}

public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> FieldViewModels 
{ 
    get
    {
        fieldViewModels.Add(new AddFieldViewModel { Header = "Add" });
        fieldViewModels.Add(new ModifyFieldViewModel { Header = "Modify" });
        fieldViewModels.Add(new ScriptFieldViewModel { Header = "Script" });
        return fieldViewModels;
    }
    private set { }
}

public ITabViewModel SelectedFieldViewModel
{
    get 
    {
        if (selectedFieldViewModel==null)
        {
            selectedFieldViewModel= FieldViewModels[0];
        }
        return selectedFieldViewModel; 
    } 
    set 
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<ITabViewModel>.Default.Equals(selectedFieldViewModel,value))
        {
            selectedFieldViewModel= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selectedFieldViewModel");
        }
    } 
}
```

Here the `ITabViewModel` is a marker interface with a property Header.

Now my problem is on tab change the views are holding on to the last states. Say In `AddFieldView` I have some dropdown and selected something. Then without doing anything in that page I moved to Modify tab and back. Then I see the drop down still holding onto the last selection. Essentially on tab change the Views are not getting refreshed with the ViewModel (unlike a webpage where menu change loads the page afresh.)

How to refresh the View with its ViewModel on tab change?

**Edit**

I tried to change `SelectedFieldViewModel` property as follows, but then views are not changing, probably because this is violating the ObservableCollection,  -

```
public ITabViewModel SelectedFieldViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (selectedFieldViewModel == null)
        {
            selectedFieldViewModel = fieldViewModels[0];
        }
        return selectedFieldViewModel;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<ITabViewModel>.Default.Equals(selectedFieldViewModel, value))
        {
            switch (value.Header)
            {
                case "Add":
                    selectedFieldViewModel = new AddFieldViewModel() { Header = "Add" };
                    break;
                case "Modify":
                    selectedFieldViewModel = new ModifyFieldViewModel() { Header = "Modify" };
                    break;
                case "Script":
                    selectedFieldViewModel = new ScriptFieldViewModel() { Header = "Script" };
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFieldViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```